# Passing javascript data to jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a click event under document.ready function like this

```
<script type= "text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
    var roll; 
    var course_code; 

         $('#table').on('click', 'button', function(){
            var obj = JSON.parse($(this).val());
            course_code = obj.course_code;
            roll = obj.roll;
            $.ajax({
                type    : "POST",
                dataType: "html",
                url     : "./card.php",
                data    : {"course_code":course_code,"roll":roll},
                success : function(returndata){
                    $("#modal-body").html(returndata);
                }
            });
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
         });
    });
</script>
```

card.php code

```
<?hph
echo '<pre>';
echo htmlspecialchars(var_dump($_POST));
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

the output from the card.php is

```
C:\wamp\www\card.php:3:
array (size=0)
  empty
```

Why i am not been able to send the data to card.php
what is the correct solution

Comment: The url should probably be `/card.php` (drop the leading `.`)

Comment: Or try to change `{"course_code":course_code,"roll":roll},` to `{course_code:"course_code",roll:"roll"},` - not sure

Comment: Also : your php script starts with `<?hph` instead of `<?php`

Comment: <? hph  is the typing mistake while posting the questing. i have used <?php in the original code. that is why i am getting the array size of post variable

Comment: @LinendraSoni what output you expecting?

Comment: when i change the second option {course_code:"course_code",roll:"roll"} the output is something like this C:\wamp\www\Exam\card.php:3:
array (size=2)
  'course_code' => string 'course_code' (length=11)
  'roll' => string 'roll' (length=4). I want to pass the variable course_code and roll the the card.php so that i can use this variable for further processing

Comment: What is `#table` and what value are you passing to it? Sounds like it is not valid json or isn't the object structure you expect

Comment: I want to output so mething like this ->                 array (size=2)
  'course_code' => string 'BSC' (length=3)
  'roll' => string '10210' (length=5)

Comment: Normally you would use multiple user input...one for each field. Not clear why you are expecting `JSON.parse()` to work. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: #table is the id of a table in which many button are created dynamically. this button have two value. i.e. course_code and roll. i have used this code in another php file somthig like this $myArr = array("roll", $roll, "course_code", $course_code);
$JOSONdata = json_encode($myArr);
echo "<td><button type='button'  value = $JOSONdata> CLICK HERE </button></td>";

Comment: my problem is that i am unable to pass the javascript variable roll, and course_code using the ajax to the card.php file

Comment: when i directly write the value of roll and course_code and using get method in the card.php. it works fine .. $("#modal-body").load('card.php?roll=121201&course_code=BAF');

Comment: Can you show the actual rendered HTML of the buttons where you are trying to get these values from?

Answer (score 0):

If your version of JQuery is more than 1.9.0 you need to replace **TYPE** to **METHOD** in your Ajax request.